# Using jasmine.any, expected and actual SEEM to match

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I'm trying to test that an express route is set in my node app using jasmine (along with jasmine-given and jasmine-stealth). I'm doing it in a loop but the gist of the comparison is (in coffeescript, incidentally):

```
route = app.stack.shift()
expect(route).toEqual
    route: ''
    handle: jasmine.any(Function)
```

I'm using jasmine.any on this particular test because the handle function comes from an express internal function (like `express.static(/*stuff*/)`). When I run the tests with grunt, I'm getting get failures with the following message:

```
Message:
 Expected { route : '', handle : Function } to equal { route : '', handle : Function }.
```

Those look the same to me. Am I missing something???

Comment: What does the 'handle' function look like above? Set a breakpoint just before the assert is made and analyze the variables in a debugging tool is my tip.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I figured it out. I'll update with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the functions that weren't matching were functions that had properties added to them. Something like:

```
var f = function() { . . . }
f.otherFunction = function() {
    console.log("Ha! You'll never know this is here!");
}
```

I ended up changing the way I was testing these anyway, but I thought it would be worth explaining the issue for anyone else who happened upon it.